# How to change the admin design in magento of order menu?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, sales-order

[image]

I wanted to change the text Additional Information to another text. The screenshot of the admin dashboard of magento of the order menu.

Can anyone say which is the path of this design in the backend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System > Configuration > Developer (under Advanced) > Debug (then change store scope to Website View in top left) > Template Path Hints` (change to Yes), and then refresh front end page.

OR

[Aoe Template hint](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints)

Use free extension called `Easy Template Path Hints` with which you can just turn on the template path hints both for frontend and backend easily using query strings.

You will get to know the file from which it is called.

in your case either it is from

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
```

or

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml
```

Comment: Hi..If I want to find the path of any other files also..this method can be used ?

Comment: yes it is for both backend and frontend. If you find this helpful then mark it as answer to close the question.

Comment: No..its not in that path..

Comment: either it can be extended but you can find it using`Easy Template Path Hints. Will you share screen shot after adding template hint query in url.

Comment: No..that extension cannot be installed :(

Comment: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints try this